# Docker Jupyter Token Authenticaion : Invalid Credential

Tags: docker, authentication, jupyter-notebook

I am following ImageCaption generation project guided by Oreilly in the following link

```
https://www.oreilly.com/learning/caption-this-with-tensorflow
```

But while I am following the github docker option A where the github correpondent to the above insturction, I installed docker and ran jupyter but keep shown with token authentication page.

```
https://github.com/mlberkeley/oreilly-captions?utm_source=newsite&utm_medium=content&utm_campaign=lgen&utm_content=caption-this-with-tensorflow-top-cta
```

But whenever I copy and paste the token I've given from the terminal windows, it keep returning `"invalid credentials"`

What would be the possible cause of it?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Also had this problem, solved it by changing

> http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=your-token

to

> http://localhost:8888/?token=your-token

Comment: http://localhost:8888/?token=your-token take you to a local instance not the one running on dockers.  I needed to change the port to get it to work.  Went for 8887 instead.

Answer (score 3):

I also had same problem, if you are using Windows: start jupyter and go to Anaconda Prompt and use this command:

jupyter notebook list

command output:

Currently running servers:

http://localhost:8888/?token=9a24db0b60370b1cb3fed2fb06b3acd316c59f50388e3711 :: C:\Users\user_name

http://localhost:8888/?token=10a787bf262f214bd14ef31f869f3090f126ba252443a048 :: C:\Users\user_name

I copy pasted the second token 10a787bf262f214bd14ef31f869f3090f126ba252443a048 from the second URL and then it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to:

1. shutdown all the opening notebooks, as the port 8888 might be used by another one.
2. map container port 8888 to your localhost port 8888

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 <your image>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the description given below, it explains the scenario pretty much.

Steps to perform:
-- Open another terminal
-- type in: jupyter notebook list
-- copy the link given here (which certainly would have a
different token)
-- paste and run it in the browser